# What is the most current way of parsing JSON in Java?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, android-activity

I am looking to parse some JSON into an Android app that I am making, it's my first app, so it's for learning more than anything else.

I followed a guide and have made this: https://github.com/LewisLebentz/Quoter

It's a very basic app that shows you quotes. All have been stored locally in the app.

So I thought I would put up a page on my website, and serve the quotes via JSON, so I can remotely add quotes.

I came across this guide: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

It works quite well, as a standalone app, but I can't work out how to integrate it into my app. Also, when adding some of the code, it tells me it is deprecated.

How should I proceed? What is the most up to date way of parsing JSON in Java? Do you know of any good tutorials.

Please keep in mind, I am a beginner; so be kind!

Answer (score 2):

Directly part of the Android SDK is org.json which is very simple to use and selfexplaining.

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Small example:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{"query":"Pizza","locations":[94043,90210]}");

if (obj.getString("query").equals("Pizza)) {
    System.out.println("It's a pizza");
}
```

As commented gson is also very suited.

https://github.com/google/gson